# Blender in 3D printing

Tags: 3d-printing

I am starting a business in 3D printing and I would like to ask you about Blender as a software for creating models of houses. Is Blender a good choice for this business? 
For example: I would get a contract from architect to create a model from 2D plan. And now: Is Blender a good choice for this type of business? Can I easily create a 3D model of that plan and print it or are there any problems like wall thickness and so on?

Comment: This question is too subjective. I wouldn't say Blender is so good for business because it's freeware and they are not responsible for any problems that happen. Go look for autodesk's software.

Comment: I do not agree with most of the comment above. and, blender is not freeware. t's more. and, it allows you to make good 3d models, even houses. but yes, choosing any software to use is subjective.

Comment: Blender is perfect for this kind of task. Being freeware or not makes no difference.

Comment: @Bradman175 You think Autodesk will reply to your emails or hotfixes the bugs you find because you paid for a licence? We have 15 licences at the office and I can tell you they don't give a flying *anything* about your case. You run into a dead end with your problem with Maya and guess what, closed software, can't do anything about it. Blender has a much better community and it is a very popular choice for 3D printing as well as the startups. Plus you can easily tinker your way around the software with python as much as you like or even compile your own custom version of Blender.

Comment: @Bradman175 - The first sentence is correct. The rest... well, as kheetor already said, paying for a license does not mean that you have better support from the Manufacturer. In every single case within the last 25+ years I used any kind of Software, my problems got solved faster with free software than with proprietary software. And please - look up the term freeware.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use Blender for 3D print modeling. Look for these addons:

1. "3DPrint Toolbox"
2. "Measureit"

These addons are not a must, but I highly recommend them, and I'm sure they will help you a lot.

Also I recommend these series:

https://store.blender.org/product/blender-for-3d-printing/

Is not free, but you save you a lot of time. You learn the correct workflow quick and with explanation, no like many people on YouTube who use Blender for two weeks (so they know almost nothing), and they think they can teach others :D